# How can develop and submit iOS app with custom dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c, dylib, dynamic-library

I think it's quite crazy but can I develop and submit an iOS app with custom dylib (also programmed by me).

I read instructions from Apple developer site about how to create dynamic library which is linked at runtime

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001908-SW1

I developed a custom dylib framework, and use it in an ios app. And I want to submit the app to Apple Store. I read somewhere that from ios 8, develop dynamic library is legible.

But I have a question, if I submit my app, users download it to their ios devices, how can these devices load and run my custom dylib (is integrated with my app)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said that dynamic framework just supports iOS 8 and above.

So your iOS application minimum target should be 8 so you can submit your application to the App Store. And users with iOS 8 can download your app.

There are another choice by making a static framework if you would like to support iOS lower than 8.